# Small abelian categories and module categories.

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, soft-question, abelian-categories

This is a soft and vague question on small abelian categories, let me explain:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck%27s_T%C3%B4hoku_paper

Wikipedia: "The article "Sur quelques points d'algèbre homologique" by Alexander Grothendieck, now often referred to as the Tôhoku paper, was published in 1957 in the Tôhoku Mathematical Journal. It has revolutionized the subject of homological algebra, a purely algebraic aspect of algebraic topology. It removed the need to distinguish the cases of modules over a ring and sheaves of abelian groups over a topological space."

In this paper Grothendieck wrote down the axioms of an "Abelian category".

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_category#Grothendieck's_axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_category#Grothendieck%27s_axioms)

The Freyd-Mitchell full embedding theorem "classifies" (in a generalized sense) small abelian categories.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitchell%27s_embedding_theorem

"The precise statement is as follows: if A is a small abelian category, then there exists a ring R (with 1, not necessarily commutative) and a full, faithful and exact functor F: A → R-Mod (where the latter denotes the category of all left R-modules). The functor F yields an equivalence between A and a full subcategory of R-Mod in such a way that kernels and cokernels computed in A correspond to the ordinary kernels and cokernels computed in R-Mod. Such an equivalence is necessarily additive. The theorem thus essentially says that the objects of A can be thought of as R-modules, and the morphisms as R-linear maps, with kernels, cokernels, exact sequences and sums of morphisms being determined as in the case of modules."
....

"However, projective and injective objects in A do not necessarily correspond to projective and injective R-modules."

**Question:** Have small abelian categories $A$ with the property that there is a functor $F$ as mentioned above where $F$ preserves projective and injective objects, been "classified"? By "classify" I mean in a "generalized" (and a bit "vague") sense - It means:

**"Which small abelian categories has such a functor?"**

Can you give non-trivial examples of small abelian categories $A$ and a functor $F$ where $F$ does/does not preserve projective and injective objects? I ask for references.

https://www.math.mcgill.ca/barr/papers/gk.pdf

Comment: The embedding is not uniquely determined, so it does not make sense to ask about its properties without first specifying which embedding is meant. It is easy to construct examples of small abelian categories with embeddings that preserve projective objects: for example, the category of finitely generated abelian groups is essentially small and its inclusion into the category of abelian groups preserves projective objects.

Comment: @ZhenLin - I changed the question - the essence of is: We would like to know which abelian categories $A$ have the property that there is an equivalence $F:A \cong Mod(R)$,   where $F$ preserve injective and projective objects.

Comment: Equivalences of categories preserve injective and projective objects. Is that really the question you want to ask?

Comment: I'm not sure why the question begins by mentioning Tohoku. This seems irrelevant to the actual question. The question could start with the discussion of Freyd-Mitchell.

Comment: Also, I would not call Freyd-Mitchell a "classification" in any sense. A classification of mathematical objects $C$ up to equivalence $\cong$ should assign some data $f(c)\in D$ to each element $c\in C$ in such a way that respects equivalence: $c\cong c'$ if and only if $f(c)=f(c')$. And ideally the equality relation on $D$ should be "simpler" than the equivalence relation on $C$. The Freyd-Mitchell theorem produces, for every small abelian category, a ring $R$ and a functor $F$ to $R\text{-Mod}$, but $R$ and $F$ are far from uniquely determined.

Comment: ...You could assign to the small abelian category $A$ the data of *all* pairs $R$ and $F$ that work, and this would classify $A$, but the resulting data is far too complicated to be a satisfying classification of $A$.